# Is there a way to create a fallback page for iframes blocked by CSP?

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm using `frame-ancestors` in our CSP to only allow embedding via iframe for certain websites. However, I would like to show some kind of message in the iframe if embedding is denied via CSP, something along the lines "Access denied, contact support". Is there a way to do that?